How can I efficiently vectorize the integrate function in R?
I am numerically integrating with integrate().  The function I am integrating depends on several parameters and I would like to calculate the integral for a large number of parameter values. I currently do this using the mapply function.
MWE:
fc <- function(x, a, b) a*x + b
fc.wrapper <- function(p.a, p.b) integrate(fc, 0, 1, a = p.a, b = p.b)$value
a.vec <- seq(0, 1, length.out = 100)
b.vec <- seq(0, 1, length.out = 100) 
system.time(mapply(fc.wrapper, a.vec, b.vec))

Output:
   user  system elapsed 
  0.003   0.000   0.004 

Problem is, in my application, this takes too long to run. So my question is, are there faster alternatives to the use of the mapply()?  I have tried using future_mapply(), but it doesn't seem to speed things up.
Tried future.apply():
library(future.apply)
plan(multisession, workers = 6L)
system.time(future_mapply(fc.wrapper, a.vec, b.vec, future.seed = T))

Output:
   user  system elapsed 
  0.315   0.008   0.752

I am also open to suggestions for faster user-written alternatives to integrate().

This might be helpful: https://github.com/yixuan/RcppNumerical

Would you mind extending your example, so it becomes computationally more costly/requires more run time? Did you investigate pracma::integrate()?

Thanks @Friede for the suggestion, pracma::quadv() seems to work best for vectorising integration, and in my application is about 6x faster than using mapply(), although on @jblood94's function below both mapply() and pracma::quadv() take about the same time.

For a 1-D smooth function, with enough memory you can use straight non-adaptive Gauss-Legendre quadrature with a relatively large number of nodes to vectorize the integration. I'll demonstrate with a function with moderate computational cost:
f1 <- function(x, A, B, C, D) {
  (A*lgamma(x) - B*log(x) + C*qgamma(pcauchy(x), 5))*exp(sin(D*x))
}

a <- 0; b <- 100 # integration extents
A <- B <- C <- D <- seq(0, 1, length.out = 20) # parameter values

I'll explore the full 20^4 parameter space by using expand.grid:
system.time({
  ba2 <- (b - a)/2 # to normalize the integration extents to [-1, 1]
  nodes <- statmod::gauss.quad(100) # calculate the nodes
  x <- nodes[[1]]*ba2 + (b + a)/2
  w <- nodes[[2]]*ba2
  df1 <- expand.grid(x = x, A = A, B = B, C = C, D = D)
  df1 <- cbind(
    expand.grid(A = A, B = B, C = C, D = D),
    v = c(crossprod(w, matrix(do.call(f1, df1), length(x))))
  )
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   23.01    0.12   23.15

Spot check the integration:
sum(f1(x, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5)*w)
#> [1] 9919.591
integrate(\(x) f1(x, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5), a, b, rel.tol = 1e-6)
#> 9919.598 with absolute error < 0.00023

If the function is amenable to broadcasting, the integration can be sped up even more using outer:
f2 <- function(x, A, B, C, D) {
  (outer(lgamma(x), A) - outer(log(x), B) + outer(qgamma(pcauchy(x), 5), C))*
    exp(sin(outer(x, D)))
}

system.time({
  ba2 <- (b - a)/2
  nodes <- statmod::gauss.quad(100)
  x <- nodes[[1]]*ba2 + (b + a)/2
  w <- nodes[[2]]*ba2
  df2 <- expand.grid(A = A, B = B, C = C, D = D)
  df2 <- transform(df2, v = c(crossprod(w, f2(x, A, B, C, D))))
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    1.45    0.05    1.52

all.equal(df1$v, df2$v)
#> [1] TRUE

This is all using a single thread. It would be straightforward to do the above in parallel.
Compare to the mapply approach in the question:
system.time({
  f3 <- function(A, B, C, D) {
    integrate(f1, a, b, A = A, B = B, C = C, D = D)$value
  }
  
  df3 <- expand.grid(A = A, B = B, C = C, D = D)
  df3 <- transform(df3, v = mapply(f3, A, B, C, D))
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>  150.28    0.04  150.58

all.equal(df1$v, df3$v)
#> [1] "Mean relative difference: 2.018989e-05"


You are measuring the time to integrate 100 times the function fc from x to x.  It's not enough to give you any relevant benchmark, especially if you consider parallelization. You should, at least, integrate over a large number of non-empty intervals (1 million for instance). Also, integrate() is already quite optimized, so my guess is that only parallelizing will help you. I'm giving you an example here, hoping that it can help you:
fc <- function(x, a, b)
  a * x + b

fc.wrapper <-
  function(p.a, p.b)
    integrate(fc, 0, 1, a = p.a, b = p.b)$value

a.vec <- seq(0, 1, length.out = 100)

abvec <- expand.grid(a.vec, a.vec)

t1 <-
  system.time(replicate(n = 200, expr = apply(
    X = abvec, MARGIN = 1, FUN = \(x) {
      fc.wrapper(x[1], x[2])
    }
  )))


t2 <-
  system.time(parallel::mclapply(
    X = 1:10000,
    FUN = \(i) {
      replicate(n = 200, fc.wrapper(abvec[i, 1], abvec[i, 2]))
    },
    mc.cores = 4
  ))

print(t1)
print(t2)

Which yields:
> print(t1)
   user  system elapsed 
 66.306   0.022  66.301 

> print(t2)
   user  system elapsed 
 86.808   0.475  29.190 

Which means that in the parallelization case, elapsed time is divided by 2. You can probably measure similar performances with future.apply package.
